# Discord.js have bot take in input from a user posting digit string

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

I'm trying to work on a bot that allows a user to use the prefix (!) and then type in a random digit string (ex !1234) which then the bot will use as an input to add into a website url to find an image. I'm new to js so I'm not really sure how to do it so if anyone could point me in the right direction that would be great!

Person types: !1234
Bot responds with: https://youtube.com/1234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is simple with [regex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions). You just search for an exclamation mark followed by a number.

```js
let str = '!1234'; //message content
let chosenNum = str.match(/!\d+/)?.[0].slice(1); //1234
//to send
<channel>.send(`https://youtube.com/${chosenNum}`)
```

If you want a certain amount of digits use this

```js
let chosenNum = str.match(/!\d{1, 4}/)?.[0].slice(1)
//1 is min, 4 is max
```

Another way you can do this, you will have to do some checks before doing this or it could have some unexpected results

```js
if(parseInt(msg.content.slice(1)) != msg.content.slice(1)) return;
let chosenNum = msg.content.slice(1);
```

Comment: Thanks! Do you know how I would be able to use it with discord.js ?

Comment: Just use `message.content.match` instead of `str.match` inside of a message event callback. Also, mark this post as correct if it helped! (Gray check mark under the upvote/downvote buttons)

Comment: so when inputting the code how would let str function if it was a different input instead of !1234? people would put in random numbers not just 1234

Comment: Don’t put `let str` at all in your code. I put that there only for testing purposes. Only use `message.content` instead. (`message.content.match(…)?.[0].slice(1)`)

Comment: Okay! How would I get their input after the prefix then? I have this

`    if (message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
        let chosenNum = message.content.match(/!\d{1, 6}/)?.[0].slice(1);
        message.channel.send(`https://youtube.com/${chosenNum}`)
    }`

Comment: That’s exactly how you do it! `chosenNum` is the number after the prefix. Now please mark my answer as correct by clicking the checkmark

Comment: Okay thanks! Anyway to make it so they dont input text instead of digits?

Comment: You put`if(!chosenNum) return message.channel.send('you need to put a number after the \`!\`')`